# Hair Rendering Issue from another angle

Tags: particles, hair

I have this issue while rendering hair object. It renders fine looking from an angle but from another angle it shows this mesh face like in the 2nd and 3rd image below. I am a beginner in Blender and modelling so I don't know how to explain the issue properly. If anyone understands, please help me out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where is *"this mesh face like in the 2nd and 3rd image"*?